# Proof that for two converging sequences and two corresponding unbound sets - the limit is equal.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Ok so I know I've seen this before phrased differently but I can't quite put my finger on the solution.
The question goes as follows:

> Let $a_n, b_n$ be two converging sequences.
>
> Also, let $\{n: n\in\Bbb{N}, a_n \leq b_n\} $ and $\{n: n\in\Bbb{N}, b_n \leq a_n\} $ be two **unbounded** sets.
>
> Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$

I'm completely drawing a blank.
I tried several approaches I know, such as Cantor's intersection theorem (which doesn't seem to fit) or other properties of converging sequences I've learned, but the question - as posed - doesn't provide enough detail (that I can see) to use any of those as far as I can tell.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks!

**Edit (possible solution?)**
After some page-turning I found a similar proof in my professor's slides and adapted it to this question. Let me know if you think it's valid:

> First we'll show that if $a_n \leq b_n $ for every $n$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$:
>
> Assuming by contradiction that if if $a_n \leq b_n $ for every $n$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n > \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$, there then exists an $n$ in $a_n$ for which $a_n>b_n$, in contradiction to the fact that  $a_n \leq b_n $ **for every $n$**, and therefor if $a_n \leq b_n $ for every $n$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$.
>
> We use the same process to prove the opposite direction, and since we have two infinite sets of indices for which $a_n\geq b_n$ **and** $b_n \geq a_n$, therefor $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$ **and** $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n$ - which means $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$ - Q.E.D.

Comment: What do you know about the subsequences of a convergent sequence?

Comment: Technically we haven't covered that topic yet, but I know from previous courses that all sub-sequences of a convergent sequence have the same sub-limit, except I can't use that because we haven't even touched the term 'subsequence' yet in class.

Comment: It just occured to me that the mentioned sets are not of members in the sequences but of INDICES. Could this help me in any way? I can't seem to think how.

Comment: But if you could use subsequences, would you see which subsequences you could take to reach the desired conclusion? If so, you can translate that idea into a proof not mentioning subsequences.

Comment: I'm assuming each of the sets is a different subsequence, but what baffles me is the mention that they're unbounded, Or is that unimportant?

Comment: As you emphasised above: _indices_ of subsequences. For subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, "unbounded" and "infinite" are equivalent, so if one of the two sets were bounded, we wouldn't have the corresponding subsequence.

Comment: Ah, fall for that again I did :-P
The indices are unbounded, but it just means there's an infinite number of members in those sets, not that those sets are unbounded. Thanks for the pointer, I'll try to develop it further.

Answer (score 0):

Let the limits be $a$ and $b.$

Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ There exist $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for $n>N_{\epsilon}$
$$
|a_n- a | < \epsilon, \; |b_n-b| < \epsilon. 
$$
or alternatively
$$
a-\epsilon  < a_n < a+\epsilon, \; b-\epsilon  < b_n < b+\epsilon.
$$
There is some such $n$ with $a_n < b_n.$ So
$$
a-\epsilon < b + \epsilon.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
b-\epsilon < a + \epsilon.
$$
So
$$
|a-b | < 2\epsilon. 
$$
But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, so $a=b.$

I call this pattern *arbitrary closeness*. (see my book "proof patterns")